Why is the frequency of LC oscillator different from the calculations?
I am trying make an LC oscillator using an op-amp with a 100mH inductor(L) and 10uF capacitor(C).
In the simulation, I am using the virtual op-amp with VCC and VDD, +12V and -12V respectively.
The switch S1 is there to start oscillation.
According to formula [ 1/(2pi(L*C)^(1/2) ) ] with the 100mH inductor and 10uF capacitor, I should get about 160Hz.
Instead, I am getting time a period (T) of 4.545ms, which according to formula [ f = 1/T ] makes frequency of signal 225Hz.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Please point out the mistake I am making.
The simulation on Multisim. The oscilloscope shows the output signal. There are cursors 1 and 2 placed on the consecutive peaks to measure the time period. We have highlighted the T2-T1, which is 4.545ms.


To make a stable sinewave oscillator you need the feedback network (between op-amp output and inverting input) to produce a phase shift of 180°. At resonance, the LC circuit you have used produces a phase shift of only 90° so, it is incorrect to assume that the formula you have listed will be accurate. In fact, in an ideal situation, your circuit would never oscillate at all because the LC circuit cannot quite achieve 180° of phase shift even at hundreds of times the resonant frequency.
So, some things to take away: -

Your formula assumption is wrong
The circuit oscillates because of parasites such as op-amp delay and parasitic capacitance
If the inductor's Q factor was much higher it will oscillate closer to the formula value
But it will oscillate in the same ball-park as the frequency produced by the formula


on second thought, i am using op-amp as inverting amplifier. the amplifier puts out a 180-phase shift.

@mubeenalamkhan yes, that's what I alluded to in my answer when I said the feedback network (between op-amp output and inverting input) <-- the full phase shift then becomes 360 degrees (equivalent to 0 degrees and a condition that must be met for oscillation to occur).

yes. i have tested with non-inverting configuration. it's working as expected.
thanks for your insight

@mubeenalamkhan if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

My analysis of the shown circuit does NOT need any parasitic quantities, see my detailed answer.

"If the inductor's Q factor was much higher it will oscillate closer to the formula value". By my analysis, the lower the Q factor, the closer the cross-over frequency becomes to the natural LC resonant frequency. However, the lower the Q, the higher the phase margin, so the less likely there will be oscillations.

Here comes my analysis:
The feedback path resembles a second-order L-C-R lowpass.
It can be shown that this lowpass

has a peak at app. 159 Hz (resonance) and
unity gain at app. fo=230 Hz with a phase shift of app. -179.6 deg at this frequency. The missing phase shift of only 0.4 deg is provided from the real and finite opamp gain.

Hence, together with an inverting unity gain amplifier (as shown in the figure) this circuit fulfills the oscillation condition at fo=230Hz. As can be seen, the circuit does not oscillate at the LC resonant frequency.
Comment: It is not necessary to start tran-simulations (time domain) with a 5V puls. Either you can switch-on the power supply at t=0 or give the capacitor an "initial condition" (an initial voltage of some mV or V)

There are two feedback paths in the original circuit. We can open one of them, to get this circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The frequency response of this circuit is


It can be seen that the gain crossover frequency is about 225 Hz, and the phase margin is approximately \$0^{\circ}\$. So, one would expect the original circuit probably would oscillate at around 225.
The circuit would only probably oscillate, because as andyaka points out in his answer, theoretically, i.e. with ideal components, the phase shift would never exactly reach \$-180^{\circ}\$. However, either with some parasitics (andyaka) or with some phase shift within the inverting unity gain amplifier (LvW), \$-180^{\circ}\$ phase shift is reached. However, the phase margin is so close to 0, that in practice, it would be exceptional if the closed loop circuit were stable.
The gain cross-over frequency, in this case is
$$f_0 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$
This is with the inductor having a theoretically 0 resistance (infinite Q). Increasing the resistance increases the phase margin, but decreases the cross-over frequency. With sufficiently low Q, the cross-over frequency approaches the natural LC resonant frequency \$f=1/2\pi\sqrt{LC}\$. However, at that point, the phase margin is so high, the closed loop circuit is very unlikely to oscillate on its own.


